# What is the total length of any interval for which $-1 \leq \tan(x) \leq1$ and $\sin(2x)\geq0.5$?

Tags: trigonometry

> What is the total length of any interval for which $-1 \leq \tan(x) \leq 1$ and $\sin(2x)\geq0.5?$

We know that $0\leq x\leq \pi$,
 $\sin(2x)\geq 0.5$ can be rewritten as $\sin(x) \cos(x)\geq \frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: you can use \leq and \geq commands for <= and >=

Comment: and \sin \cos \tan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $x \in [0,\pi]$ the condition $-1\leq \tan \, x \leq 1$ is same as $0 \leq x \leq \frac {\pi} 4$ or $\frac {3\pi} 4 \leq x \leq \pi$. For $0 \leq x \leq \frac {\pi} 4$ the inequality $\sin (2x) \geq 0.5$ is equivalent to $2x \geq \frac {\pi} 6$. Can you handle the case $\frac {3\pi} 4 \leq x \leq \pi$?

Comment: For $\sin 2x \ge \frac 12$ you also need $2x \leq \frac56 \pi $. This is relevant because $\tan x \in [-1,1]$ is also satisfied when $x\in[\frac 34\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thank you very much for pointing out the error.

Comment: Thank you very much! I can handle that case